# How to set up Spark with Zookeeper for HA?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper

I want to config **Apache spark** master to connect with **Zookeeper**

I have installed both of them and run Zookeeper.

In **spark-env.sh**, I add 2 lines:

```
-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER

-Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=localhost:2181
```

But when I start **Apache spark** with **./sbin/start-all.sh**

It shows errors

```
/home/deploy/spark-1.0.0/sbin/../conf/spark-env.sh: line 46: -Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER: command not found

/home/deploy/spark-1.0.0/sbin/../conf/spark-env.sh: line 47: -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=localhost:2181: command not found
```

I want to know how to add Zookeeper settings on spark-env.sh

Comment: looks like you didn't add those to the run command but as separate lines. Bash is interpreting them as commands.

Comment: @maasg: I did not add those to the run command. I think I could add to spark-env.sh to use ./sbin/start-all.sh

Comment: could you post the complete file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most probably you have added these lines directly to the file like so:

```
export SPARK_PREFIX=`dirname "$this"`/..
export SPARK_CONF_DIR="$SPARK_HOME/conf"
...
-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER
-Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=localhost:2181
```

And when invoked by start-all.sh, bash complains that those `-Dspark...` are not valid commands. Note that `spark_config.sh` is a bash script and should contain valid bash expressions.

Following the configuration guide at [High Availability](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#high-availability), you should set `SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS` with the options for: `spark.deploy.recoveryMode`, `spark.deploy.zookeeper.url`, and `spark.deploy.zookeeper.dir`.

Using your data, you need to add a line to `spark-conf.sh` like so:

```
export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=localhost:2181"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below line  in spark_env.sh

```
export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=ZK1:2181,ZK2:2181,ZK3:2181 -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.dir=/sparkha"
```

Please replace ZK1, ZK2 and ZK3 with your ZK quorum hosts and port 
and here /sparkha is the data store in ZK for spark , bu default it will be /spark
Just tested , it worked for us .
HTH